# How to set cookie from the backend hosted in the cloud to the frontend running on the localhost

Tags: reactjs, express

When both backend and frontend run on the localhost then cookies are being set properly,
but when i deploy the backend in the cloud then cookies are not getting set in the browser

Comment: Will need more details than this. We would need to know _how_ you're setting the cookie from the backend, at the minimum. But the more code you can provide the better

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.